# string array to datarow array

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datarow

I would like to assign string of array to a datarow array

My code is as follows

```
protected void btnGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataRow[] dRow; 
    foreach (GridViewRow grRow in grdACH.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox chkItem = (CheckBox)grRow.FindControl("checkRec");
        if (chkItem.Checked)
        {
            chkItm = true;
            chkcnt++;
            strBankTypeID += ((Label)grRow.FindControl("lblBankType")).Text.ToString();
            strBnkArray = strBankTypeID.Split(',');
            foreach (string str in strBnkArray)
            {
                //Here i have to assign my string of array to datarow
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can any one help me

Comment: what is the error, that you are getting by this code?

Comment: I am getting the error as Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Data.DataRow'

Comment: can you explain the problem you are trying to solve little more clearly, and the reasoning for solution?

Comment: Why are you needing to set an array of datarow?

Comment: @Hath : i will get multiple Id's from the selected so i have to check out by looping through foreach(datarow dr in dRow)

Answer (score 1):

you'll want to set the `GridViewRow.DataItem`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.dataitem.aspx